# MYSQL Counting the associated activities

Tags: mysql

So I need a `MySQL` query that queries a table `child`, each child then has activities.  Activities are in a related table. I want to display each child name `(fname +sname)` with the number of activities they have.

This is what I have so far but it returns an error:

```
CREATE TABLE Childactivities AS
SELECT CONCAT(`Child`.`child_fname`,' ',`Child`.`child_sname`) AS `name`
FROM Child
count activity_id as `activities`
FROM Childactivity
LEFT JOIN Childactivity
ON Childactivity.child_id=Child.child_id
GROUP BY Child.child_id
```

---

The output should be in two columns: Child name (first name and surname), and a count of
the associated activities. (This will be 0 for children with no associated activities.)

Please have a look at this [database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BApZ.png).

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Why create a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to get all childs with or without activities

```
SELECT CONCAT(`Child`.`child_fname`,' ',`Child`.`child_sname`) AS `name`, COUNT(activity.activity_id)
FROM Child
LEFT JOIN Childactivity ON Childactivity.childId = Child.child_id
LEFT JOIN activity ON activity.activity_id = Childactivity.activity_id
GROUP BY CONCAT(`Child`.`child_fname`,' ',`Child`.`child_sname`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in your query, for the join and the function count().
Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Childactivities AS
SELECT 
  CONCAT(c.child_fname,' ',a.child_sname) AS `name`,
  COUNT(a.activity_id) AS `activities`
FROM Child c LEFT JOIN Childactivity a
ON a.child_id = c.child_id
GROUP BY c.child_id, `name`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your help guys, I post here the working result:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`Child`.`child_fname`,' ',`Child`.`child_sname`) AS `name`, 
COUNT(Activity.activity_id)
FROM Child
LEFT JOIN Childactivity ON Childactivity.child_id = Child.child_id
LEFT JOIN Activity ON Activity.activity_id = Childactivity.activity_id
GROUP BY CONCAT(`Child`.`child_fname`,' ',`Child`.`child_sname`)
```

Comment: You don't need the 2nd join.

Comment: All you need is to count `activity_id`s from the table ChildActivity.